# How to disable same origin policy in cefpython?

Tags: python, webview, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I want to **disable** `same-origin policy` in [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) while using **[pywebview](https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/)**. I tried below code according to [this page](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/BrowserSettings.md):

```
from webview.platforms.cef import command_line_switches

command_line_switches.update({
     'disable_web_security': 'True' }) # if i try to put a bool as value, it shows expected bytes, not bool

if __name__ == "__main__":
   webview.create_window('', url='http://localhost:5000/')
   webview.start(gui='cef')
```

But this doesn't seem to solve the problem. I have an iframe of a different origin where I want to trigger a click event. If the security is enabled then it will throw an error with the same-origin policy message. Am I missing something? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Cefpython browser settings](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/BrowserSettings.md#web_security_disabled)

Not even the debug with cef is working, I cannot even load an image in pywebview without start a local server!!! I will switch to pyqt

**UPDATE**

It is a server side security, not a browser security!

- [Block iFrames | How to Stop Your Website From Being iFramed](https://cgscomputer.com/block-iframes-how-to-stop-your-website-from-being-iframed/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20protect%20your%20site,and%20Content%2DSecurity%2DPolicy.)

Comment: Can you give more info? Do you still have errors? Give a shout if you still experience some problems...

Comment: Hi, yes i am still experiencing the problem with disabling the same-origin policy. I tried with switch key in settings of cefpython and others but didn't really work. And also you can load an image without a local server. Please check the examples directory of the pywebview repository on GitHub. You can directly run an HTML/CSS/js in the window without needing a local server. Sure, You can switch to Pyqt but don't forget that you will miss the flexibility of using front end web techs to build UI & UX. Pywebview/eel is just a light python version of electron.js.

Comment: Do you own that origin or is a page from someone else?

Comment: of course from someone else. If I have one I could have used a window message or socket to communicate.

Comment: What I think is happening is that you are being denied by their server. Even if you disable the security of your browser, It is a setting imposed in the headers response. It is better explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: Yep. That seems to be the cause. But is there any way to even disable the header effect?

Comment: In theory, you don't. Unless the website allows the origin... it depends what is the content you wish to use from that website. Can you explicitly tell what you trying to put on the iframe? It seems you are trying to break some security measures!!! Have you tried to simulate a click on the button with javascript on that site?